# Duplicating Text In Console? (C#)

Tags: c#, console, ide, editor, neovim

So. I was trying for 4 hours to make a decently good copy of neovim written in C# and designed for Windows, which somewhat worked. However, the scrolling functionality has been giving me some issues.

When you write below the normal console window size, i'm starting to get flashy cursors etc. But for some reason it duplicates the text I have written when i scroll back up?

This is my code, specifically the Editor.Render method is the one causing it
Here's a screenshot of my problem:

[image: screen]

That's what happens when you scroll down and then back up. ^^

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;

namespace elyte3
{

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("[elyte3] Welcome to Elyte3!");
            if (args != null && args[0].Length > 0)
            {
                if (File.Exists(args[0]))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("[elyte3] File detected, opening!");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("[elyte3] Provided file does not exist.");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    return;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("[elyte3] Elyte has to be used either with a custom distro, or manual file opening with args: \n elyte3.exe <FILE PATH>");
                Console.ReadLine();
                return;
            }
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            new Editor(args[0]).Run();
        }
    }

    class Editor
    {
        private List<string> _lastRenderedContent;


        Buffer _buffer;
        Cursor _cursor;
        Stack<object> _history;

        public Editor(string filepath)
        {
            var lines = File.ReadAllLines(filepath)
                            .Where(x => x != Environment.NewLine);

            _buffer = new Buffer(lines);
            _cursor = new Cursor();
            _history = new Stack<object>();
        }

        public void Run()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Render();
                HandleInput();
            }
        }

        private void HandleInput()
        {
            var key = Console.ReadKey(true); // ReadKey without displaying the pressed key funny!

            switch (key.Key)
            {
                case ConsoleKey.Q when (key.Modifiers & ConsoleModifiers.Control) != 0:
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                    break;

                case ConsoleKey.P when (key.Modifiers & ConsoleModifiers.Control) != 0:
                    _cursor = _cursor.Up(_buffer);
                    break;

                case ConsoleKey.N when (key.Modifiers & ConsoleModifiers.Control) != 0:
                    _cursor = _cursor.Down(_buffer);
                    break;

                case ConsoleKey.B when (key.Modifiers & ConsoleModifiers.Control) != 0:
                    _cursor = _cursor.Left(_buffer);
                    break;

                case ConsoleKey.Z when (key.Modifiers & ConsoleModifiers.Control) != 0:
                    _cursor = _cursor.Right(_buffer);
                    break;

                case ConsoleKey.U when (key.Modifiers & ConsoleModifiers.Control) != 0:
                    RestoreSnapshot();
                    break;

                case ConsoleKey.Backspace:
                    if (_cursor.Col > 0)
                    {
                        SaveSnapshot();
                        _buffer = _buffer.Delete(_cursor.Row, _cursor.Col - 1);
                        _cursor = _cursor.Left(_buffer);
                    }
                    break;

                case ConsoleKey.Enter:
                    SaveSnapshot();
                    _buffer = _buffer.SplitLine(_cursor.Row, _cursor.Col);
                    _cursor = _cursor.Down(_buffer).MoveToCol(0);
                    break;

                case ConsoleKey.LeftArrow:
                    _cursor = _cursor.Left(_buffer);
                    break;

                case ConsoleKey.RightArrow:
                    _cursor = _cursor.Right(_buffer);
                    break;

                case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:
                    _cursor = _cursor.Up(_buffer);
                    break;

                case ConsoleKey.Tab:
                    SaveSnapshot();
                    int spacesToAdd = 4;
                    string spaces = new string(' ', spacesToAdd);
                    _buffer = _buffer.Insert(spaces, _cursor.Row, _cursor.Col);
                    _cursor = _cursor.Right(_buffer).MoveToCol(_cursor.Col + spacesToAdd);
                    break;

                case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:
                    _cursor = _cursor.Down(_buffer);
                    break;

                default:
                    bool IsTextChar(ConsoleKeyInfo character)
                    {
                        return !char.IsControl(character.KeyChar);
                    }

                    if (IsTextChar(key))
                    {
                        SaveSnapshot();
                        _buffer = _buffer.Insert(key.KeyChar.ToString(), _cursor.Row, _cursor.Col);
                        _cursor = _cursor.Right(_buffer);
                    }
                    break;
            }

            Render();

           
        }

        private void Render()
        {
            int visibleLines = Console.WindowHeight;
            int startRow = Math.Max(0, _cursor.Row - visibleLines + 1);

            ANSI.ClearScreen();
            ANSI.MoveCursor(0, 0);

            for (int i = startRow; i < Math.Min(_buffer.LineCount(), startRow + visibleLines); i++)
            {
                string line = _buffer.GetLine(i);
                _buffer.RenderLineWithColor(line);
            }

            ANSI.MoveCursor(_cursor.Row - startRow, _cursor.Col);
        }











        private void SaveSnapshot()
        {
            _history.Push(_cursor);
            _history.Push(_buffer);
        }

        private void RestoreSnapshot()
        {
            if (_history.Count > 0)
            {
                _buffer = (Buffer)_history.Pop();
                _cursor = (Cursor)_history.Pop();
            }
        }
    }

    class Buffer
    {
        string[] _lines;

        public Buffer(IEnumerable<string> lines)
        {
            _lines = lines.ToArray();
        }

        public string GetLine(int row)
        {
            if (row >= 0 && row < _lines.Length)
            {
                return _lines[row];
            }
            return string.Empty;
        }



        public void Render()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < _lines.Length; i++)
            {
                string line = _lines[i];
                RenderLineWithColor(line);
            }
        }

        public void RenderLineWithColor(string line)
        {
            ConsoleColor originalColor = Console.ForegroundColor;
            int currentIndex = 0;

            while (currentIndex < line.Length)
            {
                if (currentIndex + 1 < line.Length && line.Substring(currentIndex, 2) == "//")
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGreen;
                    Console.Write(line.Substring(currentIndex));
                    Console.ResetColor();
                    currentIndex = line.Length; // Move to the end of the line 
                }
                // Check for comments starting with "/*"
                else if (currentIndex + 1 < line.Length && line.Substring(currentIndex, 2) == "/*")
                {
                    int endCommentIndex = line.IndexOf("*/", currentIndex + 2);

                    if (endCommentIndex != -1)
                    {
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                        Console.Write(line.Substring(currentIndex, endCommentIndex - currentIndex + 4));
                        Console.ResetColor();
                        currentIndex = endCommentIndex + 4;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Unmatched comment just continue with default
                        Console.ForegroundColor = originalColor;
                        Console.Write(line.Substring(currentIndex));
                        Console.ResetColor();
                        currentIndex = line.Length;
                    }
                }
                // string check
                else if (line[currentIndex] == '\"')
                {
                    int endQuoteIndex = line.IndexOf('\"', currentIndex + 1);

                    if (endQuoteIndex != -1)
                    {
                        // highlight it
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                        Console.Write(line.Substring(currentIndex, endQuoteIndex - currentIndex + 1));
                        Console.ResetColor();
                        currentIndex = endQuoteIndex + 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // e
                        Console.ForegroundColor = originalColor;
                        Console.Write(line.Substring(currentIndex));
                        Console.ResetColor();
                        currentIndex = line.Length;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    int nextWhitespace = line.IndexOfAny(new[] { ' ', '\t', '\n', '\r', '\"' }, currentIndex);

                    if (nextWhitespace == -1)
                    {
                        nextWhitespace = line.Length;
                    }

                    int length = nextWhitespace - currentIndex;
                    string word = line.Substring(currentIndex, length);

                    Console.ForegroundColor = GetJavaScriptSyntaxColor(word.ToLowerInvariant(), originalColor);

                    if (currentIndex + length < line.Length)
                    {
                        Console.Write(word + line[currentIndex + length]); 
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.Write(word);
                    }

                    Console.ResetColor();

                    currentIndex = nextWhitespace + 1;
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        // bad
        private ConsoleColor GetJavaScriptSyntaxColor(string word, ConsoleColor defaultColor)
        {
            switch (word)
            {
                case "function":
                    return ConsoleColor.Magenta;
                case "if":
                    return ConsoleColor.Magenta;
                case "else":
                    return ConsoleColor.Magenta;
                case "while":
                    return ConsoleColor.Magenta;
                case "for":
                    return ConsoleColor.Magenta;
                case "var":
                    return ConsoleColor.Magenta;
                case "let":
                    return ConsoleColor.Magenta;
                case "const":
                    return ConsoleColor.Magenta;
                case "return":
                    return ConsoleColor.Magenta;
                case "console":
                    return ConsoleColor.Blue;

                case "true":
                    return ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                case "false":
                    return ConsoleColor.Cyan;

                case "null":
                    return ConsoleColor.Cyan;

                case "//":
                    return ConsoleColor.Gray;
                case "/*":
                    return ConsoleColor.Gray;
                case "*/":
                    return ConsoleColor.Gray;


                default:
                    return defaultColor;
            }
        }


        public int LineCount()
        {
            return _lines.Count();
        }

        public int LineLength(int row)
        {
            return _lines[row].Length;
        }

        internal Buffer Insert(string character, int row, int col)
        {
            var linesDeepCopy = _lines.Select(x => x).ToArray();
            linesDeepCopy[row] = linesDeepCopy[row].Insert(col, character);
            return new Buffer(linesDeepCopy);
        }

        internal Buffer Delete(int row, int col)
        {
            var linesDeepCopy = _lines.Select(x => x).ToArray();
            linesDeepCopy[row] = linesDeepCopy[row].Remove(col, 1);
            return new Buffer(linesDeepCopy);
        }

        internal Buffer SplitLine(int row, int col)
        {
            var linesDeepCopy = _lines.Select(x => x).ToList();

            var line = linesDeepCopy[row];

            var newLines = new[] { line.Substring(0, col), line.Substring(col, line.Length - line.Substring(0, col).Length) };

            linesDeepCopy[row] = newLines[0];
            linesDeepCopy.Insert(row + 1, newLines[1]);


            return new Buffer(linesDeepCopy);
        }
    }

    class Cursor
    {
        public int Row { get; set; }
        public int Col { get; set; }


        public Cursor(int row = 0, int col = 0)
        {
            Row = row;
            Col = col;
        }

        internal Cursor Up(Buffer buffer)
        {
            return new Cursor(Row - 1, Col).Clamp(buffer);
        }

        internal Cursor Down(Buffer buffer)
        {
            return new Cursor(Row + 1, Col).Clamp(buffer);
        }


        internal Cursor Left(Buffer buffer)
        {
            return new Cursor(Row, Col - 1).Clamp(buffer);
        }

        internal Cursor Right(Buffer buffer)
        {
            return new Cursor(Row, Col + 1).Clamp(buffer);
        }

        private Cursor Clamp(Buffer buffer)
        {
            Row = Math.Min(buffer.LineCount() - 1, Math.Max(Row, 0));
            Col = Math.Min(buffer.LineLength(Row), Math.Max(Col, 0));
            return new Cursor(Row, Col);
        }

        internal Cursor MoveToCol(int col)
        {
            return new Cursor(Row, col);
        }
    }

    class ANSI
    {
        public static void ClearScreen()
        {
            Console.Clear();
        }

        public static void MoveCursor(int row, int col)
        {
            Console.CursorTop = row;
            Console.CursorLeft = col;
        }

        public static void ScrollConsoleUp()
        {
            Console.MoveBufferArea(0, 0, Console.WindowWidth, Console.WindowHeight - 1, 0, 1);
            Console.CursorTop = Console.WindowHeight - 1;
            Console.CursorLeft = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Tried making switchable "pages" of code but it's not ideal